# What is terraform's init.tf for?

Tags: terraform

I'm relatively new to Terraform My current $employer uses Terraform and we have `init.tf` files in each project.

It has:

- a `terraform` block,
- `provider` blocks,
- `data terraform_remote_state` blocks

I want to understand what is this file for.

I don't see any mention of it in documentation/guides for structuring Terraform projects, e.g.:

- https://www.terraform.io/language/modules/develop/structure
- [Terraform folder structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69323678/terraform-folder-structure)
- https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-structure-a-terraform-project
- https://www.terraform-best-practices.com/code-structure

I do see some (scant) mentions of other people having this file, e.g. https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/21722

I don't see any mention of it in the terraform code base:

```
[~/git/terraform] main ± git log -S init.tf
[~/git/terraform] main ±
```

I also checked "Up and Running with Terraform" (3rd edition), no mention of init.tf

Did this used to be a convention?  What's going on here?  :)

Comment: What are its contents?

Comment: It has a `terraform` block and `provider` blocks.

Comment: And `data "terraform_remote_state"`

Comment: Any file that ends in `*.tf` will be picked up by Terraform when any of the commands are ran. In this particular case, your $employer has decided to put stuff related to provider (e.g., aws), terraform (e.g., Terraform binary constraint) and data source for fetching the remote state (for the resources already created) to a file called `init.tf`. You can try to rename it (leaving the `.tf` extension) and the behaviour will remain the same. So `foo.tf` will do the same thing as `init.tf`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is more likely that the person who named it as `init.tf` wants to convey a message that it is required to initialize terraform.

you can continue to work by run the commands - `terraform init, terraform plan` etc.

The norm is to name the file as `provider.tf`, although it doesn't matter how you name the terraform files. It can be `whatever.tf` as long as it ends with .tf